# Looping over matrices

Tags: r, loops, environment, pheatmap

thx for your help!

I have 2 matrices: Mx1 and Mx2
And I would like to make heatmaps using pheatmap by looping on selected matrices in the R environment

I tried:

```
Matrices_list <- c(Mx1, Mx2)
for( i in Matrices_list_list ){pheatmap(i, filename= "i.pdf")}
```

but obviously doesn't works
The problems is that the Df_list now is a merge of both Mx instead of 2 distinct datasets in which I cant loop. Its looping in each element of the combined Df_list

Desired output:

```
pheatmap(Mx1, filename="Mx1.pdf")
pheatmap(Mx2, filename="Mx2.pdf")
```

Thx again for your help :)

Comment: `matrices_list <- list(Mx1 = Mx1, Mx2 = Mx2) ; for(i in names(matrices_list)) pheatma(matrices_list[[i]], filename = paste0(i, ".png"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim`ension attributes (usually 2D).  The use of `c` function on two matrices, removes the dimension attributes and return a single 1 dimensional vector with `length` equal to the `length(Mx1)` + `length(Mx2)`.

As showed in the comments, if we need to keep the `matrix` as itself store it in a `list` with `names` attribute as the object names of the individual matrices.  With `dplyr::lst`, by default it generates the `names` of the `list` as object names

```
library(dplyr)
Matrices_list <- lst(Mx1, Mx2)
```

---

Regarding the `for` loop used in OP's post

```
for(i in Matrices_list ){...
```

the `i` is the individual matrix element, which doesn't have any names attribute.  This can be otherwise described as a `for` each loop i.e. for each element 'x' of 'Matrices_list'.  In other languages such as `C++`, the for each syntax would be

```
for(auto i : Matrices_list) {...
```

Instead of looping over the object elements, loop over the sequence

```
for(i in seq_along(Matrices_list)) {...
```

or the `names` attribute, extract those elements and the corresponding names to construct the file name.

---

With tidyverse, we can use `imap` or `iwalk` with `.x` the matrix element and `.y` the names of the `list` or the index (if the names are absent)

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
imap(Matrices_list, ~ pheatmap(.x, filename = str_c(.y, ".pdf")))
iwalk(Matrices_list, ~ pheatmap(.x, filename = str_c(.y, ".pdf")))
```

The difference in `imap/iwalk` is that `iwalk` doesn't print the return value on the console.